Error in Gradle while trying to run PayPal API for Payment method in my Android app
I tried to use PayPal API but I'm facing issues while running the app, the build fails and it throws this error-
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk:2.2.7-2.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jfrog/cardinalcommerce/gradle/cardinalmobilesdk/2.2.7-2/cardinalmobilesdk-2.2.7-2.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jfrog/cardinalcommerce/gradle/cardinalmobilesdk/2.2.7-2/cardinalmobilesdk-2.2.7-2.pom
- https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/org/jfrog/cardinalcommerce/gradle/cardinalmobilesdk/2.2.7-2/cardinalmobilesdk-2.2.7-2.pom
Required by:
project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:1.3.0


I opened an issue on GitHub : https://github.com/paypal/paypal-android/issues/249

I think that version was pulled from the repos. You should update the cardinal dependency to 2.7.2-5
